# PHP Javascript Variable problem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a while loop in my PHP page where I look the following...

```
    print $divLeft.strip_tags($row->twitterUser)."?size=normal\"/><br \/>".$row->twitterUser.$divRight."<a href='javascript:void(0);' id='vote_$row->id' class='getPoint'>Get " .$row->coff. "<input type='hidden' value='$row->coff' id='credoff'/> credit(s)</a><br /></div>$clearDiv</div></div>";
```

I have a value set in my hidden field which I then call in my javascript...

```
{        
   var theid = $(this).attr("id");
   var onlyID = theid.split("_");
   var onlyID = onlyID[1];
   credoff = $("#credoff").val();


    $.ajax({            
      url: 'do.php',
      type: 'POST',          
      data: "userID=" + onlyID,
      success: function(data) {
          if(data != "success1" && data != "success5") {
               $("#" + theid).text(data);  
          }else{

              $("#thediv_" + onlyID).fadeOut("slow");
              $('#creditsBalance').fadeOut("slow");
              newbalance = parseInt($('#creditsBalance').text());

          if(data != "success5") { 
              alert('Credits offered = '+credoff);
```

The only thing is in my javascript its grabbing the highest 'credoff' variable value on the page, not the one clicked on, does this make sense?

Comment: There is an indentation problem or you missed the } that closes the else

Comment: I've changed the loop input from id to class and tried 'credoff = $(this).children('input.credoff:hidden').val()'
which now returns undefined, I've also tried

'var credOff = $(this).find('input').val();' which breaks my JS and stops the rest of the code like alert and fade in execute...

Comment: what is in 'this'?  How is the function getting called?

Comment: Perhaps you made a typo in my function.  Here's a base fiddle showing the base selectors working:

http://jsfiddle.net/ehNKJ/

Answer (score 0):

First off, $('#credoff') is an id... and IDs are unique to a page.  Secondly, if there were more than one (and built properly through a CSS selector), the way you're calling $('#credoff') would only give you the value of the first one, since you're not associating it with the event target.

Since it looks structurally like the input is a child of the  (which is odd, too, btw), you'll need to use a selector like this to get credOff:

```
$('.getPoint').click(function(){
    // properly associated with the event target.
    var credOff = $(this).find('input').val();
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Element IDs must be unique throughout the page; if they are not, then attempting to select by ID is undefined.  Your best bet is to use something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" ... class="credoff" />
```

And then in the javascript something like this:

```
credoff = $(this).children('input.credoff:hidden').val()
```

Comment: This is returning Undefined, Is it possible I can give the input a name and use var credoff = getelementbyname(credoff).value; ?